# Is WebORB suitable for Java -> .NET remoting and messaging

Tags: java, .net, weborb

Does WebORB supports writing desktop clients in .NET (eg. WPF) and consuming remoting and messaging services in Java server using BlazeDS?
Alternatively, can BlazeDS in Java server be replaced by WebORB for Java without changing existing clients written in Flex?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start by asking this question on the [WebORB forum](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/forum/).

I do think WebORB supports writing desktop clients in .NET as they have supported SilverLight in the past. I also think you can replace the BlazeDS by WebORB for jave as the AMF specification remains the same.

WebORB comes with a lot of examples, so your first questions should be quickly answered by looking at these examples.

I would suggest to use REST instead of AMF, but that's just me.

Answer (score 0):

> Does WebORB supports writing desktop clients in .NET (eg. WPF) and
>   consuming remoting and messaging services in Java server using
>   BlazeDS?

The .NET version of WebORB has an communication library for the desktop applications (http://www.themidnightcoders.com/fileadmin/docs/dotnet/v5/_net_client_overview.htm) and as you will see, the Remoting/RPC, Publish/Subscribe messaging, and RTMP data messaging are available with the library.

Some time ago, I did a simple example when the windows service communicates with the server and sends some data do it. The server updates data in its turn updates all connected FLEX clients. Although in example I used the WebORB server, I believe it could be replaced with any similar solution. The example in details and some code are available on my blog http://blog.scriptico.com/06/120/

> Alternatively, can BlazeDS in Java server be replaced by WebORB for
>   Java without changing existing clients written in Flex?

I would say it could be replaced yet it depends how did developers write it. In the past, I had some experience with the migration from BlazeDs to WebORB. In the best case, you will not touch the FLEX client at all or just re-build it with the modified channel endpoint information.